# What font is used for the uservoice.com logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, logo

See [www.uservoice.com](http://www.uservoice.com), they have this beautiful geometric font and I would love to find out what it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easily seen that the logo is the same as the text on the page. The CSS for at least one element contains

```
font-family: "Avenir LT W01 35 Light";
```

**Avenir** looks like [this](http://www.myfonts.com/search/avenir/fonts/):

[image: Example of Adobe Avenir]

There are a number of versions and weight variants.

Comment: I think you're right, with the exception of the dot on the i

Comment: A dotless i is Unicode U+0131. It'll be included in OTF font files.